# How to echo randomly a portion of a string?

Tags: php, string, substring, quotes

i have already succesfully translated some quotes via my translation function `__();` and now I want to **echo only one of those quotes at random**. All quotes are separated in this string with a special character like a `|`

Sofar I only have this. What code could should go below this tackle my random echo?

```
$quotes =
__("IF YOU MAKE EVERYTHING BOLD, NOTHING IS BOLD") . "|" .
__("Quality of design is an indicator of credibility") . "|" .
__("People ignore design, that ignores people");
```

*(An important restriction: it is essential that the quotes be exactly closed with  `__("`  and `");` sothat they can be checked and translated.)  `__($variable)` doest not work with current clean up scripts that I have bought so these won't work.*

Comment: You can't just use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)? e.g. `_(array_rand(array("STRING ONE", "String two", "String three")));` or `$quotes = array_rand(array(_("STRING ONE", "String two", "String three")));` (granted array_rand returns keys, but just portraying the point)

Comment: @Brad, unfortunately no! in this particular case.

Comment: To clarify: Is `__` a function in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already calling `__()` on each of your quotes individually, why not save all the extra translating and do something like:

```
$quotes = array('quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3');
$index = array_rand($quotes);
echo __($quotes[$index]);
```

**Edit:** To satisfy your other requirement, that the call to `__()` must immediately surround each string, you could do this:

```
$quotes = array(__('quote1'), __('quote2'), __('quote3'));
$index = array_rand($quotes);
echo $quotes[$index];
```

The big downside here is that you're now looking up a translation for every string in that array, even though only one is printed, but that's the same situation you had in the "one big string" solution.

Comment: the cleanup script searches for __("....") and __($variable) does not work with my translation script!

Comment: If it's important for you to have the `__()` immediately around the string literal, that would still work fine with an array (though you lose the side benefit of avoiding translating strings you're not outputting).

Answer (score 1):

Why the *biscuits* are they all in one string, and not an array? Your problem would be immediately solved if this was the case. As stands, split in `|` and index randomly into the array created to pick a random quote.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep them in an array and translate only what is actually outputted?

```
$quotes = array(
    "IF YOU MAKE EVERYTHING BOLD, NOTHING IS BOLD",
    "Quality of design is an indicator of credibility",
    "People ignore design, that ignores people",
);
$randomQuote = $quotes[ rand(0, count($quotes)-1)];
echo __($randomQuote);
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, I don't thing you should use a comma here: "design,".

Comment: While you are right on that comma, the __($var) wont work!  I added the comma actually to show that a comma cannot be uses as a delimiter to cut the scring open